# How did my teacher go from this step to another? | Advanced Functions | Trigonemetry

Tags: trigonometry

The question was

Solve. $\sqrt{2}\cos x + \cot x = 0,\ x\in [-\pi, \pi]$

So she did

$\sqrt{2}\cos x + \frac{\cos x}{\sin x} = 0$ which is fine

But the next step confuses me. I understand where she went from this next step, but not how she got to it.

$\cos x(\sqrt{2} + \frac{1}{\sin x}) = 0$.

What I'm not understanding is, is how the $\sqrt{2}$ left the '$\cos x$' and joined the $\frac{1}{\sin x}$, and how the $\frac{\cos x}{\sin x}$ even became $\frac{1}{\sin x}$?

Any help would be great.

Comment: Your teaching factored out the $\cos(x)$. Namely this step is from the distributive rule.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a use
of the distributive law
which states that,
for any real
numbers
$a, b, c$
we have
$a(b+c) 
= ab+ac
$.

In your case,
you have
$0
= \sqrt{2}\cos x + \dfrac{\cos x}{\sin x}
$.

Your teacher then
used the distributive law
(and other laws)
to write

$\begin{array}\\
0
&=\sqrt{2}\cos x + \dfrac{\cos x}{\sin x}\\
&=\cos x \sqrt{2} + \cos x\dfrac1{\sin x}\\
&=\cos x \left(\sqrt{2} + \dfrac1{\sin x}\right)\\
\end{array}
$

If you still do not understand this,
please get some help,
because you *have* to understand
algebra at this level
to have any chance
of understanding
the other material
you will be taught.

Comment: Honestly, I've never heard of 'distributive law', but after this explanation, I make myself look dumb. I guess just adding in the sinx and cosx makes it look harder than it really is. Next time, I'll just use a let statement. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: Do you understand my explanation?

Comment: Yes, I understand it. Basically like, a = sqrt(2) b=cosx c=sinx .....
ba + b x 1/c.....
Divide b out.....
b(a + 1/c)

Comment: Good. Trig functions can turn into each other in a number of ways, so you just have to get experience manipulating them.